# Auto Resize Page Size In Phone And Other Screen Size

Tags: html, css

i learned css in w3 school and i just created a page where it's work as what i want , but if i use inspect element / at phone / other device with smaller screen , it's irregular , especially at the text , i don't know where i missed , here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Here You Put Code */
body {
background-image:url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CYQ5F9q6YlE/VIX6zgIg8EI/AAAAAAAAGwU/nkOudSDpI18/s1600/website-background-rough-surface.jpg");
}
div {
margin:30px;
margin-top:20px;
}
.NODDOS {
font-size:60px;
position:absolute;
border:2px solid black;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
padding:160px;
padding-top:50px;
padding-bottom:50px;
width:65%;
font-weight:bold;
}
.abcdefg { 
font-size:30px;
}
.DONOTHACKUS {
position:absolute;
margin:30px;
margin-top:310px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.DONOTHACK {
font-size:20px;
color:black;
background:;
border:3px solid black;
padding:10px;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #888888;
text-decoration:none;
}
#home {
background : #C2DFFF;
}
.DONOTHACK:hover {
position: relative; 
top: -1px;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #888888;
}
.DONOTHACK a.hahaha {
text-decoration: none;
color:#000000;
}
.DONOTHACK a.hahaha:link {
text-decoration: none;
color:#000000;
}
.DONOTHACK a.hahaha:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color:#000000;
}
.DONOTHACK a.hahaha:active {
color:blue;
}
.maybeimtooshy {
font-size:50px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.butimustkeeptry {
position:absolute;
margin-left:310px;
margin-top:350px;
}
.totalkwithher {
font-size:20px;
}
.alltime {
position:absolute;
margin-top:600px;
border-bottom:5px solid black;
width:94%;
}
.keeptryjustrun {
position:absolute;
margin-top:595px;
margin-left:100px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:50px;

}
.keeptrynoshy {
font-weight:normal; 
font-size:30px;

}
.ihopeshewillloveme {
height:50px;
width:300px;
}

/*-------------------*/
<!-- Mazaya Salma Zhafarina -->
<!-- I Love You             -->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="NODDOS">English Lesson
<p class="abcdefg">Welcome To English Lesson !</p>
</div>
<div class="DONOTHACKUS">
<div class="DONOTHACK" id="home"><a class="hahaha" href="#">Home</a></div>
<div class="DONOTHACK"><a class="hahaha" href="#">Tentang</a></div>
<div class="DONOTHACK"><a class="hahaha" href="#">Kerjakan Soal</a></div>
</div>
<div class="butimustkeeptry">
<div class="maybeimtooshy">
Siapa Kita ? 
</div>
<p class="totalkwithher">
Kita adalah anggota SMP 13 Semarang yang membuat website ini untuk melatih kemampuan siswa
<p class="totalkwithher">
dalam berbahasa inggris melalui soal soal yang diberikan
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="keeptryjustrun">
Daftar Sekarang !
<p class="keeptrynoshy">Ayo Daftar Sekarang Dan Kerjakan Soal Untuk Menjadi Yang Terbaik !</p>
<button class="ihopeshewillloveme" href="#">Daftar Disini !</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

anyone know where im missed ? 
-EDIT- fixed some word

Comment: What does "messed up" mean? If you don't tell us the specific problem, we can't help you.

Comment: messed up mean irregular , also the problem in the text

Comment: If these names for classes are real, then you should probably change them because these names tell you nothing about what they do and therefore they are bad names.

Comment: "Irregular" is just as non-descriptive as "messed up"; you need to provide us with details of your specific problem.

Comment: oh crap ..... :\ guess u can't help me only because that , i sleepy and there is alot of class ....

Comment: gonna just delete and re-ask tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to do... First of all, you will need to put this in your `head` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It makes sure mobile devices don't just make your desktop site smaller (i.e. unreadable without zooming).

Next, you'll need "media queries" in your CSS, like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  ...
  [ put CSS rules for screens below 960px width in here ]
  ...
}
```

You can use several media queries, for tablets, smartphones in different sizes etc.

This is the essential part - it's a lot of work...

Comment: now where to put the media queries ?

Comment: nvm i tag this as usefull and go learn :)

Comment: At the bottom of your CSS code, in your case inside the `<style>` tag. (i.e. just before `</style>`)

Answer (score 0):

its too lengthy to solve entire code. plz i suggest use bootstrap in your code. For a beginner its  a easiest way to learn responsive design.
please refer to this link [Bootstrap Getting started page](http://getbootstrap.com)